# Delete entry that is connected to 2 tables

Tags: mysql

table 1 is called (athlete) and table2 is called (training_session.id) the primary key to table 1 is ID, and the table 2 has the primary key Athelete_id

I want to delete a person from my database by using his name, which I've called "Pet". However, he is also connected to another table which stores his training session. So (ID 1) on table 1 is connected to table 2 (athlete id1)

I struggle a lot, I try using INNER JOIN.

```
DELETE athlete,training_session FROM athlete
    INNER JOIN
    training_session ON training_session.id = athlete.name 
WHERE
    athlete.name = "Pet;
```

I have something wrong with my syntax, is it correct to use Inner Join or have I misunderstood

Comment: Hint: Open quotes, close quotes.

Comment: why does this not work? do u know why??

Comment: DELETE athlete, training_session
    FROM athlete
    LEFT JOIN training_session
    ON training_session.athlete_id = athlete.name
    WHERE athlete.name = "Per persen"

Comment: So, what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

You should have set up foreign key constraints with Cascade deletions to simplify the logic and all you would have needed than was to delete from athlete. So I would suggest you add it.

For more info you can take a look at:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/